# grep/sed/awk - Replace all "$X" in file with new computed value "$X/10"

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

This is my original file:

```
#Game No : 1000693
***** 888poker Hand History for Game 1000693 *****
$1/$2 Blinds No Limit Holdem - *** 18 11 2021 10:41:44
Table DD Poker 9 Max (Real Money)
Seat 7 is the button
Total number of players : 9
Seat 1: Monroe ( $2 )
Seat 2: Mpeti ( $2 )
Seat 3: Bowen ( $2 )
Seat 4: Riccardo ( $2 )
Seat 5: Ramman ( $2 )
Seat 6: Reva ( $2 )
Seat 7: Miklos ( $2 )
Seat 9: Samlet ( $2 )
Seat 10: Geralyn ( $2 )
Hamlet posts small blind [$1]
Geralyn posts big blind [$2]
** Dealing down cards **
Monroe calls [$2]
Mpeti folds
Bowen folds
Riccardo folds
Ramman folds
Reva folds
Miklos calls [$2]
Hamlet folds
** Dealing flop ** [ As, 6s, Ah ]
** Dealing turn ** [ 8s ]
** Dealing river ** [ 4h ]
** Summary **
Monroe shows [ Jh, Td ]
Miklos shows [ Tc, Jc ]
Samlet shows [ Th, 8c ]
Geralyn shows [ Js, Ts ]
Geralyn collected [ $17 ]
```

For all the dollar values "$X" I need to replace them with "$X/10" (Eks. $2/10=0.2)
I am able to extract the dollar values and divide them with 10 with this piped command:

```
grep -o '\$[[:digit:]]*' dollar.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | awk '{print $1/10}'

0.1
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.2
```

How can I alter the whole original file (or create a new file) so that the rest of the file consist while all the "$X" values are replaced with "$X/10"?

Comment: There's no reason to use sed or grep at all here; this code could be reasonably and efficiently implemented as 100% awk... though personally, I'd reach out for Python on this one.

Comment: (the thing Python has built-in, that one has to do by hand in awk, is a the ability to pass a function to use to calculate the replacement value to the standard library's regex-based find-and-replace feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
#Game No : 1000693
***** 888poker Hand History for Game 1000693 *****
$1/$2 Blinds No Limit Holdem - *** 18 11 2021 10:41:44
Table DD Poker 9 Max (Real Money)
Seat 7 is the button
Total number of players : 9
Seat 1: Monroe ( $2 )
Seat 2: Mpeti ( $2 )
Seat 3: Bowen ( $2 )
Seat 4: Riccardo ( $2 )
Seat 5: Ramman ( $2 )
Seat 6: Reva ( $2 )
Seat 7: Miklos ( $2 )
Seat 9: Samlet ( $2 )
Seat 10: Geralyn ( $2 )
Hamlet posts small blind [$1]
Geralyn posts big blind [$2]
** Dealing down cards **
Monroe calls [$2]
Mpeti folds
Bowen folds
Riccardo folds
Ramman folds
Reva folds
Miklos calls [$2]
Hamlet folds
** Dealing flop ** [ As, 6s, Ah ]
** Dealing turn ** [ 8s ]
** Dealing river ** [ 4h ]
** Summary **
Monroe shows [ Jh, Td ]
Miklos shows [ Tc, Jc ]
Samlet shows [ Th, 8c ]
Geralyn shows [ Js, Ts ]
Geralyn collected [ $17 ]
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^0-9]|([0-9]*)";OFS=""}{dollar=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if(dollar){$i*=0.1};dollar=($i=="$")};print}' file.txt
```

output

```
#Game No : 1000693
***** 888poker Hand History for Game 1000693 *****
$0.1/$0.2 Blinds No Limit Holdem - *** 18 11 2021 10:41:44
Table DD Poker 9 Max (Real Money)
Seat 7 is the button
Total number of players : 9
Seat 1: Monroe ( $0.2 )
Seat 2: Mpeti ( $0.2 )
Seat 3: Bowen ( $0.2 )
Seat 4: Riccardo ( $0.2 )
Seat 5: Ramman ( $0.2 )
Seat 6: Reva ( $0.2 )
Seat 7: Miklos ( $0.2 )
Seat 9: Samlet ( $0.2 )
Seat 10: Geralyn ( $0.2 )
Hamlet posts small blind [$0.1]
Geralyn posts big blind [$0.2]
** Dealing down cards **
Monroe calls [$0.2]
Mpeti folds
Bowen folds
Riccardo folds
Ramman folds
Reva folds
Miklos calls [$0.2]
Hamlet folds
** Dealing flop ** [ As, 6s, Ah ]
** Dealing turn ** [ 8s ]
** Dealing river ** [ 4h ]
** Summary **
Monroe shows [ Jh, Td ]
Miklos shows [ Tc, Jc ]
Samlet shows [ Th, 8c ]
Geralyn shows [ Js, Ts ]
Geralyn collected [ $1.7 ]
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is either (0 or more digits) or single any other character using `FPAT`. Then I iterate over fields using `for` loop, firstly I replace field with 0.1 of value if `dollar` variable holds true, then I set `dollar` variable to true if field is equal to `$`. Order is crucial, as this mean first operation is to field immediately after dollar field. After processing all fields in line I `print` it. I set output field separator (`OFS`) to empty string, to prevent injecting unwanted characters.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 5):

If you can use `perl` for this, the solution will be as short as

```perl
perl -i -pe 's{\$(\d+)}{($1/10)}ge' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/iUmXp6). *Details*:

- `-i` - inline file changing option
- `s{\$(\d+)}{($1/10)}ge` - a `s`ubstitution command, where the RHS (replacement part) is a Perl expression (this is enabled with the `e` flag), matching all (`g`) occurrences on each line of a `$` symbol and then one or more digits (captured into Group 1, `$1`), and replacing each match with the result of division of the Group 1 value by 10.

If you want to explicitly forbid to perform substitution of float values (e.g. as in `$10.500`), you can replace `\$(\d+)` with `\$(\d+)(?!\.?\d)`.

Comment: Here I see  the `perl` power `replacing each match with the result of division of the Group 1 value`. Simple and efficient; 1+

Answer (score 3):

One implementation of this, as a pure awk script (no bash required), might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
/[$][[:digit:]]+/ {
  while (match($0, /[$][[:digit:]]+/) > 0) {
    prefix = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1)
    suffix = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    input = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)
    output = input / 10
    $0 = prefix output suffix
  }
}
{ print }
```

If run with `./awkscript <in.txt` or `awk -f awkscript <in.txt`, output is:

```
#Game No : 1000693
***** 888poker Hand History for Game 1000693 *****
0.1/0.2 Blinds No Limit Holdem - *** 18 11 2021 10:41:44
Table DD Poker 9 Max (Real Money)
Seat 7 is the button
Total number of players : 9
Seat 1: Monroe ( 0.2 )
Seat 2: Mpeti ( 0.2 )
Seat 3: Bowen ( 0.2 )
Seat 4: Riccardo ( 0.2 )
Seat 5: Ramman ( 0.2 )
Seat 6: Reva ( 0.2 )
Seat 7: Miklos ( 0.2 )
Seat 9: Samlet ( 0.2 )
Seat 10: Geralyn ( 0.2 )
Hamlet posts small blind [0.1]
Geralyn posts big blind [0.2]
** Dealing down cards **
Monroe calls [0.2]
Mpeti folds
Bowen folds
Riccardo folds
Ramman folds
Reva folds
Miklos calls [0.2]
Hamlet folds
** Dealing flop ** [ As, 6s, Ah ]
** Dealing turn ** [ 8s ]
** Dealing river ** [ 4h ]
** Summary **
Monroe shows [ Jh, Td ]
Miklos shows [ Tc, Jc ]
Samlet shows [ Th, 8c ]
Geralyn shows [ Js, Ts ]
Geralyn collected [ 1.7 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `.2` is sufficient for `0.2`, you could just put a dot before the last digit of each dollar value:

```
sed -E 's/(\$)([0-9]*)([0-9])/\2.\3/g
```

Otherwise (improved, thanks to potong's suggestion):

```
sed -E '
    s/\$([0-9]+)([0-9])/\1.\2/g
    s/\$([0-9])/0.\1/g' file
```

- For dollar values containing two or more digits, remove `$` and put a dot before the last digit (effectively dividing by 10).
- Any remaining dollar values have one digit. Remove `$`, and put `0.` before the digit.
- This won't work if the input can contain decimal dollar values already (like `$10.00`)

Comment: For the second solution perhaps `sed -E 's/\$([0-9]+)([0-9])/\1.\2/g;s/\$([0-9])/0.\1/g' file`?

Comment: @potong yep that is functionally the same and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing and the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'match($0,/(.*\$)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] a[2]/10 a[3] } 1' file
```

```
$ cat file
#Game No : 1000693
***** 888poker Hand History for Game 1000693 *****
$1/$0.2 Blinds No Limit Holdem - *** 18 11 2021 10:41:44
Table DD Poker 9 Max (Real Money)
Seat 7 is the button
Total number of players : 9
Seat 1: Monroe ( $0.2 )
Seat 2: Mpeti ( $0.2 )
Seat 3: Bowen ( $0.2 )
Seat 4: Riccardo ( $0.2 )
Seat 5: Ramman ( $0.2 )
Seat 6: Reva ( $0.2 )
Seat 7: Miklos ( $0.2 )
Seat 9: Samlet ( $0.2 )
Seat 10: Geralyn ( $0.2 )
Hamlet posts small blind [$0.1]
Geralyn posts big blind [$0.2]
** Dealing down cards **
Monroe calls [$0.2]
Mpeti folds
Bowen folds
Riccardo folds
Ramman folds
Reva folds
Miklos calls [$0.2]
Hamlet folds
** Dealing flop ** [ As, 6s, Ah ]
** Dealing turn ** [ 8s ]
** Dealing river ** [ 4h ]
** Summary **
Monroe shows [ Jh, Td ]
Miklos shows [ Tc, Jc ]
Samlet shows [ Th, 8c ]
Geralyn shows [ Js, Ts ]
Geralyn collected [ $1.7 ]
```

If you want the `$`s removed from the output then just change `\$)` to `)\$` in the regexp used in `match()`.

The above assumes you only have 0 or 1 `$<number>` per line and that all numbers are integers.